# Class as dictionary key in swift

Tags: swift

How i can use class as dictionary key?
example

```
class Base:NSObject{}
class A:Base{}
class B:Base{}

var map:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]

map[A.self] = "lalala";
```

update, found some conversion. It work, but I can't explain.

```
let any: AnyObject = A.self as AnyObject;
let key = any as! NSObject;
print(key.hash);
```

Comment: Indexing by a class is simply impossible. There is obviously a bad design decision that causes you to try it. If absolutely needed (which is unprobable), you can use class name.

Comment: How do you want to use this dictionary?
If you want to respond to different classes differently, then maybe creating your own protocol and extensions for all relevant classes is more appropriate.

Comment: I need dictionary  (Class : objectOfClass). Where I can get object by Class, remove object by  Class and add object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that `A.self` will simply not be an `NSObject`. Changing your dictionary definition to `[AnyObject:AnyObject]` will fail because `AnyObject` is not hashable. You could use one of `NSObject`'s hashable class methods, e.g. `.description`...

```
class Base: NSObject {}
class A: Base {}
class B: Base {}

var map:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:] // A.self in Swift will not be an NSObject
//var map:[AnyObject:AnyObject] = [:]// AnyObject does not conform to Hashable

map[A.description()] = "lalala"
let c = map[A.description()] // "lalala"
//map[A.self] = "lalala" // Cannot subscript [NSObject : AnyObject] with index A.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you need:

```
class Base:NSObject{}
class A:Base{}
class B:Base{}

var tempDict:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]

tempDict["\(A.self)"] = "lalala"

tempDict["\(A.self)"]    //"lalala"
```